# Updated (edited) a closed question, try reopening it

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Some days ago I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769169/problems-and-with-wich-algorithm-technique-they-can-be-solved) at SO which was unfortunately closed.
After some days, I thought updating my question and used the reopen feature. It seems though that it needs 4 other reopen votes from SO users for the question to be opened.

The problem is that as the question is closed, none is looking at the question and so none will probably find my changes and vote for reopening the question. Is there a way I could inform other users of my updates so that my question would have one more chance?

Well, although not so much time have passed since editing my question I didn't see even a slight increase on the number of views of the question (which is usually something I see when editing my open questions).

Comment: I don't think your edits really fixed the problem. Questions that ask for a "list" of something aren't really on-topic here. If you have a specific question about algorithms, that would be perfectly on-topic. But as it stands, I don't personally feel compelled to vote to re-open that one.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I see. Thanks for pointing that to me :)

Comment: That's kind of an issue with a Q&A site set up like this one is. We tried poll, discussion, and list style questions before on Stack Overflow (you'll still find a few from way back in '08 and early '09 when the site had just started), but they didn't really work out. It's best to ask specific, targeted questions about a particular problem. That way, the best answer to the problem floats to the top. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more details about which types of questions are best to ask (and which types you shouldn't ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flag the question for moderator attention and ask them to reopen it, or draw attention to it here on meta, as you've done.